# If B is countable then A is countable.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, set-theory

> Let $A$ and $B$ be sets and suppose that $A⊆B$. If $B$ is countable then $A$ is countable.

I'm pretty much sure this has been asked before however my question is more about the logical path of the proof itself.

We still haven't studied many theorems at class, so I'm trying to use what we've learned and allowed to use during proofs writing.

We've proofed that the interval $(0,1)$ is uncountable and so $\Bbb R$ is uncountable.
Then my idea was doing this:

The theorem is logically equivalent to:  If $A$ is uncountable then $B$ is uncountable.

Then if I assume the opposite, namely, I assume that A is uncountable $\Rightarrow B$ is countable
and then I use the fact that $(0,1)$ is not countable, however $\Bbb R$ is uncountable.

Does it logically proof the initial theorem?
Thanks

Edit: first time using the forum, so edited it a little bit. Sorry and thanks

Comment: Which one is the subset, $A$ or $B$?

Comment: B is the main, A is the subset. Sorry for the confusion, fixed.

Comment: I don't think $(0,1)$ being uncountable has much to do with this. Are you trying to say that if a subset is uncountable, then the entire set is uncountable?

Comment: I mean (0, 1) is a subset of R. I tried to contradict the opposite theorem using it because that's what we learned is true

Comment: $\{0\}\subset\mathbb N$ seems to be a counter-example. The statement is true if you replace "countable" with "at most countable" (i.e., finite or countable).

Comment: Yeah, but you have to actually construct the contradiction.  Why would $(0,1)$ being uncountable but $\mathbb R$ being countable be a contradiction?  (And you *can't* say "because we know it isn't" because that has nothing to do with the excercise or anything you've done.)

Comment: If you consider A and B as infinite sets (the other cases seem to be immediate).  Then would it be logical to prove the way I depicted?

Comment: Countable sometimes includes finite and sometimes does not.  For your proposition to be true you must be including finite in countable.  What is your definition of countable?  If it is an injection into $\Bbb N$,

Comment: @KentaS 
I know that formally I can't say that but during homework and class we are allowed to immediately use some theorems we've proofed during recitations etc. Then I was interested to know if the way I claim is logical

Comment: No.  That is not a prove.  You can't just make up a case that doesn't work assume it does and then say because we know it doesn't that is a contradiction.  That what be like trying to prove all primes greater than $2$ are odd by saying:  Take $11$, suppose this thereom is false and lets assume $11$ is even.  But $11$ *isn't* even.  That's a contradiction.  So the theorem is true!..... That is *exactly* the same as what you are trying to do.

Comment: @RossMillikan Ikr. So if I separate the cases and use this claim when the set & subset is infinite (the other cases seem to be much easier)

Comment: All you've done is shown there is *one* case where the theorem is true.  As a proof you have proven:  The statement is not always false.  But you have in no way shown the statement is always true.

Comment: "Then if I assume the opposite, namely, I assume that A is uncountable ⇒B is countable"  Aah!  But that's your problem! The opposite of $A \implies B$ is *NOT*  $A\implies \lnot B$.  The opposite of $A \implies B$ is:  There exists at least one case (*not* every case) where $A$ is true and $B$ is not.

Comment: If countable includes finite you do not need to separate cases.  If countable does not include finite the statement is false.  You need to look at your definition to decide which.  It is hard when courses decide on a definition which has an accepted alternative if they do not admit there is one.  The students may not realize there is another standard definition.  This is one of the big ones, another is whether $0$ is a natural number.

Comment: @fleablood 
Damn, 2 hours ago it seemed so obscure and now it's so obvious. Thank you so much

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to understand what the underlying structure of the statement is, sometimes theorems omit the structure because they assume the reader knows it, or, perhaps, their professors will fill the gaps for them.

This is what your theorem is **actually** saying,

$\forall A,B$ such that $A\subseteq B$, if $B$ is countable, then so is $A$.

Or,

$$\forall A,B[A\subseteq B \implies (|B| \leq |\mathbb{N}| \implies |A| \leq|\mathbb{N}|)]$$

There is a theorem in logic normally called substitution theorem (or substitution of equivalents) that says for a formula $F(P(x))$ if $P(x)$ is equivalent to $Q(x)$ then $F(Q(x))$ is equivalent to $F(P(x))$.

In this case,

$$|B| \leq |\mathbb{N}| \implies |A| \leq |\mathbb{N}|$$

is equivalent to

$$|A|> |\mathbb{N}|\implies B > |\mathbb{N}|$$

So you ought to prove the following,

$$\forall A,B[A\subseteq B \implies (|A|>|\mathbb{N}|\implies B >|\mathbb{N}|)]$$

Now going back to your proof attempt, you say that "we use that $(0,1)$ is not countable, however $\mathbb {R}$ is uncountable".

Here what you are doing is giving a particular instance of the theorem, not proving the general theorem. Notice that the statement is universally quantified so you will have to show that it holds for **any** two sets such that $A\subseteq B$.

I am not gonna prove this for you because you didn't ask for a proof, this is just an explanation of why your argument logically doesn't work - which is what exactly you asked for.

Comment: From the last part, I tried to say like: suppose not >|ℕ| and then use this R, (0,1) instance to contradict it. I guess this is the part where I was mistaken?

Comment: @X4J yes, that's where the problem is, you are proving an existential by doing that. You need this to hold for **any** two sets. You can't prove general statement by giving example of that statement... for example, $7$ is odd, $21$ is also odd, therefore any multiple of $7$ is odd but this is obviously wrong.

Answer (score -1):

You made a mistake when you took the contrapositive. The contrapositive of if $A$ is uncountable then $B$ is uncountable is if $B$ is countable then $A$ is countable, which is what you are trying to prove.